# jquery animate function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In the following JQuery code the animate function is not working:

```
$('#current_item').css({'background-color':'#88ff88'}).animate({'background-color' : '#114411'}, 1000);`
```

can anyone help me about finding the reason

Comment: what was the error? check the console of your browser

Answer (score 0):

You cannot animate background colours without using additional plugins. From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height,
>   or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the
>   jQuery.Color() plugin is used).